# How to convert the output format of decrypt_iv() function to text in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, function, encryption

I am using the following definition for the postgres functions:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS EncryptStringWithIV(text);
create or replace function EncryptStringWithIV(email text) returns bytea as '
declare
  Key text;
  IV text;
  value bytea;
begin
  select sStringValue into Key from XtkOption where sName=''Key''; 
  select sStringValue into IV from XtkOption where sName=''IV'';
  value = encrypt_iv($1::bytea, Key::bytea, IV::bytea, ''aes'');
  return value;
end;
' language plpgsql
;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS DecryptStringWithIV(bytea);
create or replace function DecryptStringWithIV(email bytea) returns bytea as '
declare
  Key text;
  IV text;
value bytea;
begin
  select sStringValue into Key from XtkOption where sName=''Key''; 
  select sStringValue into IV from XtkOption where sName=''IV'';
  value = $1;
  return decrypt_iv(value, Key::bytea, IV::bytea, ''aes'');
end;
' language plpgsql
;
```

This is my output when the fn. is called :

`EncryptStringWithIV('123')`  - \x8dd75f487a7b45e73fbe365545f0506a
`DecryptStringWithIV('\\x8dd75f487a7b45e73fbe365545f0506a')`  - \x313233

Should I be converting the output format to get back the exact text value (123)? I am not able to figure out where exactly I am going wrong. any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your functions return a `bytea` and the default way of display such a "blob" is hex encoded in Postgres. If you want a proper number, then change your code to return a proper number, not some binary value

Comment: Yes, I tried encoding the encrypted value as base64 to get a text o/p and then decoding it back in the decrypt fn from base64 before decryption. It worked fine then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode to get it from `bytea` to `text`.

```
encode(DecryptStringWithIV('\\x8dd75f487a7b45e73fbe365545f0506a'), 'escape')
```

Or change your decrypt function:

```
create or replace function DecryptStringWithIV(email bytea) returns text as '
declare
  Key text;
  IV text;
value bytea;
begin
  select sStringValue into Key from XtkOption where sName=''Key''; 
  select sStringValue into IV from XtkOption where sName=''IV'';
  value = $1;
  return encode(decrypt_iv(value, Key::bytea, IV::bytea, ''aes''), ''escape'');
end;
' language plpgsql
;
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks, for your answer. I used `dec = decrypt_iv(value, oppoKey::bytea, oppoIV::bytea, ''aes'');
  return encode(dec, ''escape'');` and it gave the correct output for `DecryptStringWithIV(EncryptStringWithIV('123'))` as 123, but for `DecryptStringWithIV('\\x8dd75f487a7b45e73fbe365545f0506a')` it still gives \x313233.

Comment: @Tweety  Can you check to see if you have more than one `DecryptStringWithIV()` function defined with a different parameter type?

Comment: I tried this encrypt with `encode(encrypt_iv($1::bytea, Key::bytea, IV::bytea, ''aes''),''base64'')` and decrypt with `value = decode($1,''base64'');
  dec = decrypt_iv(value::bytea, oppoKey::bytea, oppoIV::bytea, ''aes'');
  return encode(dec,''escape'');` And it seems to work fine now. Thanks for your guidance.